# How can I apply Bootstrap position classes on specific screen sizes?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have this HTML element with Bootstrap5 utility classes for position:

```
<div class="position-absolute bottom-0 w-100 text-center mb-2">
  Content
</div>
```

I need to remove the class `position-absolute` on the mobile screen using bootstrap utilities

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap [position classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/position/) are not responsive (except for [sticky](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/helpers/position/#responsive-sticky-top)). You'll need to create your own custom class. You may be able to use [breakpoint mixins](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/breakpoints/#media-queries) to automatically get the breakpoint sizes:

```
@include media-breakpoint-only(xs) {
    .position-xs-only-absolute {
        position: absolute;
    } 
}
```

Otherwise, use standard [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) which correspond to Bootstrap's [breakpoints](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/breakpoints/#available-breakpoints).

```
@media (max-width: 575px) {
    .position-xs-only-absolute {
        position: absolute;
    } 
}
```